# How to upload file to AWS S3 using accessKey, secretKey and token?

Tags: android, amazon-s3

I need to upload file into AWS S3. I have only accessKey, secretKey and token, I get it all from third-party server.

I am trying to do it with this code:

```
mClient = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicSessionCredentials(accessKey, secretKey, token));
mClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
mUtility = new TransferUtility(mClient, mContext);
TransferObserver observer = mUtility.upload(mBucketName, remotePath, new File(localPath), CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
```

But always get Access Denied error. How to upload file correctly with accessKey, secretKey and token?

Comment: Check if the bucket exists and you have access to it.

Comment: @VaradChemburkar, yes, it is exists and I have access. I know it exactly because application for another OS works well with this bucker. But I have no access to source code of this another application.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create [AmazonS3Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#AmazonS3Client-com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials-) with [BasicSessionCredential](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/BasicSessionCredentials.html)

`mClient = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicSessionCredential(accessKey, secretKey, token));`

Comment: BasicAWSCredentials have only two arguments. It doesn't have token.

Comment: `tokens` expire after a certain time.

Comment: I don't cache it. I receive it from third-party server and immedetially put it in BasicSessionCredential.

Comment: You will have to check Bucket Permissions. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTpolicy.html

Comment: But application for another OS works well with same credentials, same third-party server and same bucket. That's mean that the permissions is ok.